# A error when unzip a zipped file that contains a very long filename on Windows system

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here, I got a zipped file from Linux, now I want to unzip all files in my Windows PC. but I got a error that said the file name was too long to write to system.

Now I just have a idea that before I write to disk, firstly I can change the filename in memory, then loop the file list, change the file name to a proper one, then write it to disk. how can I implement that in Python?

Does *zipfile* can help me? I try to write some codes to implement my solution here:

```
import os
import zipfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile('c://jekyll-export.zip', 'r')
    # before I extract to local directory,
    # how can I change the file name? 
    zf.extractall()  # this can not works
```

---

Yes, I get a version that can works! but anyone can give a better solution? or suggestions?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile('c://jekyll-export.zip', 'r')
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
    i = 0
    try:
        for info in zf.infolist():
            i += 1
            print info.filename
            original_name = urllib.unquote(info.filename)
            print original_name
            out_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'output') + original_name
            print type(out_path)
            #print os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(out_path))
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(out_path)):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(out_path))
            buffer_size = 16 * 1024
            with zf.open(info) as fin, open(unicode(out_path, 'utf-8'), 'w') as fout:
                while True:
                    buf = fin.read(buffer_size)
                    if not buf:
                        break
                    fout.write(buf)
    except (WindowsError, IOError) as e:
        print str(e)

    print i
```

Comment: yes. I have code, but code is so simple, so I didn't paste my code here.

Comment: I paste my code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however you won't use `extract` (that keeps the original filename), but rather unpack manually using `open` and `read`:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip) as zf:
    for info in zf.infolist():
        outpath = create the output path (original path is in info.filename)
        bufsiz = 16 * 1024 # or more to speed things up

        with zf.open(info) as fin, open(outpath, 'w') as fout:
            while True:
                buf = fin.read(bufsiz)
                if not buf:
                    break
                fout.write(buf)
```

Comment: Yes, it works! read first, then change the file name, and write to new file.

Answer (score -1):

Use pkzip rather than winzip.  WinZip doesn't seem to support the long filenames.

Comment: So to whoever marked this down:  Well I have direct evidence that pkzip works where WinZip fails.